# How to setup GitLab - Debian 8

Tags: debian

I am executing the below command, however i get an error.  Someone please assist.

```
# curl https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/debian/jessie/gitlab-ce_8.1.2-ce.0_amd64.deb/download
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate is not yet valid
```

If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Try `-k` or `--insecure` option to ignore ssl certification error.